# fgrep failing with carriage return at the end of a line

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I have two files which are nearly identical. The second file contains extra lines.

> file1

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

> file2

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

With the use of fgrep, I'm trying to display the lines from the second file, which aren't present in the first:

```
fgrep -wvf file1 file2
```

This usually works, except in the case where there is an extra, blank line (LF) at the end of *file1*.

Why would fgrep fail to return anything in this case and is it possible to rectify, while still using fgrep?

Comment: What system are you using and what are the rest of the line endings in each file?

Comment: @TomFenech, Using OS X and file2 ends at the '5' of the line containing 'Line 5', so doesn't contain a CR/LF

Comment: look for non-printing chars in both files with `cat -vet` on each file, in case one has \r and the other not, for example.

Comment: @meuh, that displays the $ sign, to show the end of line characters, with file1 having a $ on the line after *'Line 3'*, so nothing unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

When file1 contains a blank line, that *empty pattern* matches every line, so `fgrep -v` will show nothing.

You can compare *sorted* files with `comm`, eg

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: That seems like a logical explanation. Do the files need to be sorted, as it seems to match correctly without calling sort?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight The sorted need only comes in when the files start to differ, and `comm` wont move past the next line in file1 until it is <= a line in file2, for example.  So, in reality they both need to be sorted. Also, I'm not convinced by my own explanation of an empty line matching all because I forgot you add `-w` and this stops it matching all, on my fgrep anyway. oops.